# Allow users to use -D (--chdir) option with sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I want to make user `bob` able to use the `-D` option in `sudo` (like `sudo -D /home bash` which would open a root shell on `/home`).

How can I do this and what are the security implications to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option is relatively new (the [Changelog entry](https://www.sudo.ws/releases/changelog/) that introduced the feature is from 2020-09-01 and Ubuntu support was only introduced starting Ubuntu 21)

[`man sudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/sudo.8.html)

```
 -D directory, --chdir=directory
             Run the command in the specified directory instead of the current working
             directory.  The security policy may return an error if the user does not have
             permission to specify the working directory.
```

The associated settings in [`/etc/sudoers`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man5/sudoers.5.html) are:

```
 runcwd        If set, sudo will use this value for the working directory when running a
               command.  The special value “*” will allow the user to specify the working
               directory via sudo's -D option.  See the Chdir_Spec section for more details.

  ....
 Chdir_Spec

 The working directory that the command will be run in can be specified using the CWD
 setting.  The directory must be a fully-qualified path name beginning with a ‘/’ or ‘~’
 character, or the special value “*”.  A value of “*” indicates that the user may specify the
 working directory by running sudo with the -D option.  By default, commands are run from the
 invoking user's current working directory, unless the -i option is given.  Path names of the
 form ~user/path/name are interpreted as being relative to the named user's home directory.
 If the user name is omitted, the path will be relative to the runas user's home directory.

 This setting is only supported by version 1.9.3 or higher
```

I don't have a suitable system at hand, but I think that you can allow users `alice` and `bob` permission to use `-D` with:

```
# /etc/sudoers or include from /etc/sudoers.d/
...
# Modify the defaults for the members of User_Alias USERLIST

Defaults:USERLIST   runcwd=*

# User alias specification

User_Alias  USERLIST = alice, bob
```

As to the security implications: I don't feel qualified to say if there are any risks,  or if it offers new avenues of abuse. I couldn't find any recommendations in favour or against `runcwd=*`  yet with a cursory search either.